# Php efficiently set read timeout on HTTPS requests

Tags: php, soap, curl, https, timeout

Is there a way to efficiently set a timeout on an **https** request in php?

There is a [solution](https://gist.github.com/2654079) with curl simulating a SOAP request, however it is significantly slower.

Benchmarking it against a slow service shows an average of 6.5 seconds instead of 5.5 seconds the SOAP Client takes for the same request.

There is an alternative of [stream socket](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-client.php)
(implemented by Zend Framework on ZendHttpClientAdapterSocket) however the
stream_set_timeout function does not seem to work on https connections.

Please **note** that the issue is the read timeout (time to get a response) and not the connect timeout (time to do the handshake) which works on both http and soap requests

Finding a solution to make curl faster would resolve the issue as well.

**USER STORY**
I am making requests on an external https soap webservice using zend soap client.
The service usually responds on average on 5.5 seconds when the network is ok.
When there are network issues however, some requests take up to 7 to 8 minutes 
consuming server resources.

I can use curl and force a timeout and then i am solving my problems when there are network issues with the webservice.
However my average response time goes up to 6.5 seconds when the network is ok
The business requirement suggests that requests that take longer than 30 seconds should rather be dropped in order to ensure stability of the system.

Comment: I don't get it: you want to set a read timeout but making curl faster is fine too? What is your actual problem?

Comment: Frits, I updated the question to answer your comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you're using other than cURL.

If you're using streams you can just use [`stream_set_timeout`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-timeout.php) (which sets the read-write timeout).

The connect timeout you can specify in `fsockopen` or however you create your stream.

---

See if you can specify a read-write timeout in your SOAP client?

Comment: Have you tried if this works on https? I know that it works on http.

Comment: Yes, I have (with great success). Your server needs mod_ssl enabled though or the ssl_stream_filter wont be available and PHP will throw an error. There is no difference between http and https at the level you're working on, they are interchangeable.